# Force GORM to treat one-to-one relationships as independent

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a  `MyParameter` class and a `MyParameterValue` class defined as follow:

```
class MyParameter {
  MyParameterValue defaultValue

  static belongsTo = [anotherObject: AnotherDomainClass]
}

class MyParameterValue {
  MyParameter valueOf
}
```

My problem is that **GORM insists to treat this a one-to-one relationship** with back reference, which is not what I want. It has implications on how parameters are updated.

*Example:*

```
    def param = new MyParameter(defaultValue: new MyParameterValue()).save()
    def paramVal = new MyParameterValue (valueOf: param).save()
    assert param.defaultValue != paramVal
```

This code throws an `AssertionFailure`. So what happened? Although it should be clear that I did not meant to modify the default value of `param` on the second line, GORM updates it as if `defaultValue` had to be synchronize with `valueOf` in `MyParameterValue`,

So GORM actually transforms what I want:

[image: UML Example of two references in opposite direction]

into that:

[image: UML Example of two-sided one-to-one relationship]

Here are my two questions:

- What is the purpose of the `hasOne` keyword if all references that, from the type point of view, look like back references, are treated as a one-to-one relationship anyway?
- How can I force GORM to not treat `valueOf` as a back reference of `defaultValue`? Note that I don't want to change the cascading behaviour: changing the `defaultValue` of a `MyParameter` should be cascaded.

**Update**

I'm still interested in an answer to the question above. The solution I used was to give default values their own class `MyDefaultValue`. As you could guess, `MyParameterValue` is a complicated structure and I was looking for a way to avoid duplicating this structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want any back-reference, but want to handle all relations manually, I think I would define my objects like this:

```
class MyParameter {
  MyParameterValue defaultValue

  static constraints {
     defaultValue nullable: true
  }
}

class MyParameterValue {
  MyParameter valueOf

  static constraints {
     valueOf nullable: true
  }
}
```

But this requires, that you do all the plumbin yourself.

Comment: OK, I was not aware that `nullable` has an influence on back referencing. I will try that.

Comment: There is no belongsTo involved in the relationship in my example.

Comment: I just tried with `nullable: true` in both relations, but the behavior is exactly the same as in my question (relation is updated in MyParameter).